# Logger for multiple users

Tags: c#, logging

Logger For Multiple users write to file at a time.

I am using Logger in my Application. It is working fine for single user at a time. But for multiple users it showing an exception as, `System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\19-Oct-2015_TraceLogFile.txt' because it is being used by another process.`

The logger.cs page code below.

```
public static class Logger
{
    static string ErrorLogFile, TraceLogFile;

    static Logger()
    {
        string fpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["telogpath"];

        ErrorLogFile = fpath + string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now) + "_ErrorLogFile.txt";
        TraceLogFile = fpath + string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now) + "_TraceLogFile.txt";

    }

    private static string GetExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        string retValue = string.Format("Message: {0}\r\nStackTrace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            retValue = retValue + string.Format("\r\n\r\nInner Exception: {0}", GetExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException));
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    public static void WriteException(Exception ex, string AdditionalInfo)
    {
        string finalMessage = string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff}: {1}\r\n\r\nAdditional Info: {2}\r\n{3}\r\n\r\n", DateTime.Now, GetExceptionMessage(ex), AdditionalInfo, new string('-', 60));

        File.AppendAllText(ErrorLogFile, finalMessage);
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string Message)
    {
        string finalMessage = string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff}: {1}\r\n", DateTime.Now, Message);

        File.AppendAllText(TraceLogFile, finalMessage);
    }
}
```

and accessing like below.

```
 Logger.WriteLine("Hello");
 Logger.WriteLine("Process started");
```

Please help to solve the issue.

Comment: If your users create a new process each only one will be able to access the log file at a time. Show us the code, perhaps it can be changed. But perhaps it is easier either to centralize logging or use a logfile with the username in it

Answer (score 0):

C#, not Java...

That aside, files typically get locked when they are open for write, in order to prevent dirty writes.  This is the same on most OS and most programming languages. I'd rather go and use a database or named logfiles per user/date if you really need that kind of functionality.

Harder Alternative: Read up on Mutexes

Slowing down the System Alternative: Close the File every time, after Writing, retry until the file is available again.

Comment: New here, so didn't know i could try to edit that as well. :)